# how to reduce the time taken to load a HTML page using HTMLagilitypack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Actually i am working on such project in which i need to get contact page link from all the website displayed by google search results. I managed to achieve this by individually loading all the url using Load method ( HTMLweb ). But it takes a huge amount of time to load all the url one by one and then fetch the contact page address.

Here is the function i am using to get contact page URL.
i am passing the website URL as an argument (which was fetched by google search result)

```
private string GetContactPageFromURL(Uri url)
{

     //HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    try
    {
        var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb() { AutoDetectEncoding = false, OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2"), };

        string str = getHtmlWeb.Load("http://" + url.Host).DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href,'contact')]")[0].Attributes["href"].Value;
        if (!str.StartsWith("http://") && !str.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            if (!str.Contains(url.Host))
            {
                if (!str.StartsWith("/"))
                    str = "/" + str;
                str = url.Host + str;
            }
            str = "http://" + str;
        }

        return str;
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't complete but I think you'll have more chances by making the fetching concurrent (a thread per url). IO is the perfect context for gaining huge performance improvements with multiple threads.